# Работа с 2D камерой в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, камера, 2d

Недавно начала изучать Unity3D, и столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой: в Unity3D очень неудобно работать с камерой в плане ее размеров на разных разрешениях, ну или я чего либо не понимаю.

Мне необходимо что бы игра на iPhone и iPad выглядела идентично, за исключением того что на iPad камера растягивается вниз/вверх, т.е. что бы по ширине на обоих устройствах было все одинаково.. но сделать у меня это не получается из-за неудобной настройки камеры - нельзя просто задать постоянных размер по ширине и что бы он не менялся.

На iPhone (16/9) все как надо, но вот на iPad (4/3) камера увеличивает высоту тем что просто отрезает длину, иначе говоря зумит пока не будет заполнен весь экран, но мне надо что бы она не зумила, а просто растянулась вверх/вниз - может кто подсказать как это реализовать?

**UPD:** Добавил на камеру скрипт со следующим кодом:

```
Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
float cameraHeight = 10.0f; // Нужное значение размера камеры
float desiredAspect = 16.0f/9.0f; // Соотношение под которое подобран размер
float aspect = camera.aspect;
float ratio =  desiredAspect / aspect;
camera.orthographicSize = cameraHeight * ratio;
```

В целом все работает как надо, но может есть еще другие способы?

Comment: Статья по теме: «[Hor+vert+ FOV, или адаптивное поле обзора](https://habrahabr.ru/post/168077/)».

Comment: @Arhad для 2D Orthographic камеры это не подходит..